# Is there a way to automatically add custom HKEY_CURRENT_USER reg keys for new users?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

Windows 7

I have a third-party software application that requires a custom key/value to be added under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\FOO\FOO2\FOO3\`.  This presents a problem for brand new users whoe share the same system since their default HKCU setup won't have this custom key.  Is there an easy way to tell Windows to add a certain key to HKCU for all users?

I understand that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is intended for these types of "global" keys but the software app doesn't support that. It needs to find it under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Is a logon script the only option here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it for *all* new users in the future,
and it’s the same value (data) for all,

- Create a dummy user (let’s call it `bekim`).
- Login as `bekim`,

  - insert the desired key/value(s) with Registry Editor (`regedit`) or `red add`,
  - and logout.
- As Administrator, with “Hide protected operating system files” unchecked,
  copy `\users\bekim\NTUSER.DAT` to `\users\Default\NTUSER.DAT`. 
  (You should probably backup the old version first.)

Comment: Wouldn't that replace the default-user file (and everything it contains), with what is in the bekim file?

Comment: Well, yes; that's the point. It's my understanding that the `NTUSER.DAT` file of a _newly created user_ will be a copy of `\users\Default\NTUSER.DAT` – so, after logging in to the newly created user for the very first time, and making _one_ configuration/settings change, `\users\bekim\NTUSER.DAT` will be a copy of `\users\Default\NTUSER.DAT` plus that one change.

Comment: A "well, duh!" moment.  Not being a network guy, I've probably misunderstood the purpose of the default user since Windows first came out.  My understanding had been that the default user was common, baseline settings that apply to all users, and the individual user profiles supplement that.  So, the overlap never made sense for that explanation.  It finally makes sense.  Definitely +1 material.  And congrats on passing 2K.

Comment: @fixer1234: Thank you. (And Woo Hoo!)